# How to make sure an individual page from a website is not indexed by search engines?

Tags: google, search-engines, search-engine-indexing, web-crawlers

I'm setting up a personal website with a blog that I would like to be indexed by  search engines. But the blog will link to CV with personal information that shouldn't be indexed.

Can it be reliably achieved without publishing that personal content in non-document format (e.g. image)?

Comment: Do you want to keep the _page_ out of search engines, or just the _information_ on it?  Yes, it turns out [there's a difference](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24569/why-do-google-search-results-include-pages-disallowed-in-robots-txt).

Comment: If you want the information to remain private (i.e. not available online) do not post it online - [scraper bots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) do not respect robot exclusion protocols.

Answer (score 7):

If it's a HTML document, include [the following meta tag](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) in it:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

This will tell Google and every other search engine that understands the tag (which should be pretty much all of them, since it's been around since 1996) not to index the page.

For non-HTML documents, you can configure your webserver to send the HTTP header `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` instead.  This is a somewhat newer feature, but it's understood at least by the major search engines like [Google](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/07/robots-exclusion-protocol-now-with-even.html), [Yahoo!](http://www.ysearchblog.com/2007/12/05/yahoo-search-support-for-x-robots-tag-directive-to-simplify-webmasters-control-and-weather-update/) and [Bing](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/webmaster/archive/2009/08/21/prevent-a-bot-from-getting-lost-in-space-sem-101.aspx).

Yet one more way to keep search engines away from a page is to disallow it in your [`robots.txt` file](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).  However, [there's an important caveat](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24569/why-do-google-search-results-include-pages-disallowed-in-robots-txt): Google, at least, treats `robots.txt` as a prohibition against *fetching* the disallowed pages, but *not* against including their URLs in their index if they're linked from another page they've crawled.  And you can't effectively combine `robots.txt` with the meta tag or HTTP header based methods, since disallowing a page in `robots.txt` will keep Google from ever even seeing any meta tags or HTTP headers on it.

(However, if you disallow a page in your `robots.txt` *and* send Google a removal request for it, they'll keep it out of their index.  But that's a somewhat laborious and error-prone method.)