# What is better for SEO robots.txt file or dynamically generated robots.txt URL?

Tags: wordpress, web-crawlers, robots.txt, search-engine-indexing

I was relying on our custom WordPress package's dynamically generated *robots.txt* URL for a few sites but it was not being honoured by Google or Bing (plugin URLs were getting indexed despite the rule `Disallow /wp-content` in *robots.txt*). I waited for a couple of weeks and uploaded an actual file in the root with the same rules and it worked.

Does this mean that an actual file is better than dynamically generated *robots.txt* file or is it just me associating some coincidental events?

Comment: They both looks the same to the search engines. They can't tell if one is dynamic and another is not.

Comment: Are you sure the plugins folder was blocked in the original dynamic robots.txt? As the default dynamic robots.txt of wordpress does not block wp-content folder.

Comment: @Max Yes, the company I work for has a custom wordpress package that generates a /robots.txt url (if robots.txt file is not present) with the rules recommended here: http://www.askapache.com/seo/updated-robotstxt-wordpress.html Didn't realise that wordpress does not have `wp-content` blocked by default, thanks for pointing that out, I have edited my question to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference to search engines between those two methods. You can generate it like you want.

Moreover, you need to know blocking a page with *robots.txt* is not the perfect way to prevent indexing of pages.
You can read [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24569/why-do-google-search-results-include-pages-disallowed-in-robots-txt) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

No difference at all as far as crawlers are able to access them (with all your valid rules) with HTTP 200 response.

Comment: Please pay attention of posting an answer with additional information in relation to these already mentioned in other answers.